# Why is my commonName repeating the same in my loop?

Tags: json, swift, loops, for-loop

[from this link](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/Victoria/to/Bank?nationalSearch=False&timeIs=Departing&journeyPreference=LeastTime&walkingSpeed=Average&cyclePreference=None&alternativeCycle=False&alternativeWalking=True&applyHtmlMarkup=False&useMultiModalCall=False&walkingOptimization=False&app_id=6573044a&app_key=7a97df35339dc68625384077a5e07304) I am getting out the same commonName but it should be different?!

```
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
let object = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
let json = JSON(object)

for (_,object):(String, JSON) in readableJSON { 
    let commonName = json["toLocationDisambiguation"]["disambiguationOptions"][0]["place"]["commonNam‌​e"].stringValue 
    commonNameArray.append(commonName)
}
```

Comment: but I am expecting to get a different value out for each?!

Comment: is it cos I'm setting my variable inside the For loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the [0], you need to do something like

```
var i = 0
for (_,object):(String, JSON) in readableJSON { 
    let commonName = json["toLocationDisambiguation"]["disambiguationOptions"][i]["place"]["commonNam‌​e"].stringValue 
    commonNameArray.append(commonName)
i = i+1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, you're always grabbing only the `0`th element of the `disambiguationOptions` array. Instead, you need to use an index to get each element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is meaningless, it iterates through the key/value pairs of the top dictionary but uses none of them. Instead you are retrieving always the same object using the same reference starting at the top level, too.

The base array object containing the `commonName` keys is `disambiguationOptions`.

This code iterates through all items of the array.

```
var commonNameArray = [String]()
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let readableJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
let object = JSON(readableJSON)
let disambiguationOptions = object["toLocationDisambiguation"]["disambiguationOptions"]
for option in disambiguationOptions.arrayValue {
  let commonName = option["place"]["commonName"].stringValue
  commonNameArray.append(commonName)
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I'll give this a try when I get home, Thank you..and thanks to others who helped me!

Comment: I tried this and it very nearly worked, it seems to output correctly when I NSLog it but I get a fatal error: Array index out of range

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587724/why-do-i-get-array-index-out-of-range

Comment: I tested exactly that code successfully in a Playground

Comment: yes, as I said it outputs correctly but it breaks the app and errors?!

Comment: An `out of range` error is not related to that code.

Comment: Must be in my .count

Comment: `count` is never out of range.